# Как узнать текущую ветку и элейес репозитория на сервере git?

Tags: git

Есть сервер *git*, туда я поставил web-интерфейс, и надо прикрутить *ctags* на файлы, для этого надо обработать каждый *push* в *hook'ах*, решил я сделать две ветки на репозитории origin:

- *master*
- *dev*

Надо теперь как то узнавать элейес репозитория (*origin* или др.), и ветку, по *http* такая информация не передается.

проделал я в локальном репе:

```
git checkout dev 
git commit -am message 
git push origin dev`
```

**после этого я посмотрел файл *head*:**

**в *.git/HEAD* на клиенте:  `ref: refs/heads/dev`

на сервере `ref: refs/heads/master`**

*dev* была создана после *master*

но *HEAD* по сути должен же указывать на последний коммит в дереве изменений?
Почему на сервере *master*?

---

вот еще выполнил на сервере:

```
grep dev $(find . -name "*")
grep: .: Это каталог
grep: ./branches: Это каталог
grep: ./logs: Это каталог
grep: ./logs/refs: Это каталог
grep: ./logs/refs/heads: Это каталог
grep: ./hooks: Это каталог
grep: ./objects: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/48: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/64: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/23: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/85: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/0d: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/c8: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/a5: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/5a: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/c6: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/4b: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/50: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/91: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/pack: Это каталог
Двоичный файл ./objects/pack/pack-382c3207511c9c58c83e7d34690c5d3615876bf0.pack совпадает
grep: ./objects/45: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/ab: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/1f: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/41: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/2e: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/dd: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/2f: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/62: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/b9: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/info: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/ad: Это каталог
grep: ./objects/30: Это каталог
grep: ./refs: Это каталог
grep: ./refs/tags: Это каталог
grep: ./refs/heads: Это каталог
grep: ./info: Это каталог
./info/refs:4869dddb814126c310e424276797f4bf0ea7540a    refs/heads/dev
```

то есть, может быть информация о ветке хранится в .pack файле? который по сути является хеш-таблицей(архивом) всего проекта.

Comment: "но HEAD по сути должен же указывать на последний коммит в дереве изменений?" - после клонирования и уж тем более просто пуша - никак нет.

Comment: На сервере с большой вероятностью bare репозиторий. А в этом случае понятия "текущая ветка" не имеет смысла.

Comment: @KoVadim ну в инструкциях по настройке сервера надо указывать bare репозиторий, веротяно, да. Но репы создаются через web интерфейс и потом клонируются на машину.

Comment: @KoVadim можно ли как то преобразовать его в non-bare?

Comment: *можно ли как то преобразовать его в non-bare?* — `git config core.bare false`. но будьте осторожны — `push` в такой репозиторий по умолчанию будет отклонён.

Comment: теоретически можно, но смысл?

Делайте генерацию тегов на локальной машине.

Comment: В bare репозитории нет файлов в рабочем каталоге (working directory). Нет файлов - нет текущей ветки. 
Да, есть прописаный HEAD, но это используется с другой целью.

Comment: @KoVadim на локальной машине нельзя, нужно чтобы по тегам можно было переходить в веб-интерфейсе

Comment: сделайте рядом на сервере копию репозитория, куда клонируйте нужную ветку, делайте все, что хочется - запускайте ctags.

А если клонировать с параметром -l, то даже можно сильно сэкономить место.

Comment: @KoVadim Я так и делал, вот именно что нужно знать какая ветка, все на хуках, да в общем то, если поставить хук перед коммитом, в котором будет генерироваться файл, затем добавляться в реп, то наверное можно, сейчас почитаю о хуках pre-commit

Comment: Не выйдет делать тэги на локальной машине, нужно делать на сервере полсе push

Answer (score 3):

**предварительное напоминание**

в *git*-е веткой (*branch*) называется «скользящий» указатель на *commit*, а не *набор commit-ов*, как принято в некоторых других системах управления контролем версий.

---

> но HEAD по сути должен же указывать на последний коммит в дереве изменений? Почему на сервере master?

в *bare*-репозитории файл HEAD ссылается на «ветку по умолчанию», что в первую очередь влияет на результаты клонирования этого репозитория: если при клонировании не указано, на какую ветку следует переключить рабочий каталог (*working directory*) по окончании клонирования, именно на эту ветку и произойдёт переключение.

> может быть информация о ветке хранится в .pack файле?

информация о ветках хранится в каталоге `refs/heads`. в описанном вами репозитории там должно быть по крайней мере два файла `master` и `dev`, содержащие хэш коммита, на который в данный момент и указывает соответствующая ветка.

Comment: Я имел ввиду информацию о текущей ветке и элейесе репозитория. Мне никак достать эту информацию в  bare репозитории?

Comment: если под термином «текущая ветка» вы подразумеваете ветку, которая развёрнута в рабочем каталоге, то в случае bare-репозитория он не имеет смысла — там просто нет рабочего каталога **рядом с репозиторием**. один только «голый» (bare) репозиторий.

Comment: надеюсь, вы уже поняли, что пытаетесь идти неправильным путём. задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос о том, как можно автоматизировать генерацию ctags, вооружившись уже полученной информацией.

Comment: вот теперь каким то магическим образом появился на сервере /refs/heads/dev до этого не появлялся, но HEAD все равно указывает на master

Comment: всё правильно же написано, что не подошло-то...